# Why doesn't my popover work?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I now want to use a popover for which I try to use the following HTML:

```
<div
     class="col-xs-12 right-column-block panel panel-default pointer"
     data-toggle="popover"
     data-placement="bottom"
     data-content='this is the popover content'>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Click for popover
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the popover doesn't show on click. Since the code is rather basic and I don't get any console errors I don't really know how to proceed. I've got a [running example of this code here](http://185.53.129.139:5000/).

Could anybody help me out here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: have you included this `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});`

Comment: @IamRaviteja - Ah, that was it. It was in there, but commented out (whoever did that sucks). I knew it had to be something stupid. Thanks! Can you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I yust added data-container="body" to your div and worked for me, or maybe you just uncommented that out :)

Comment: I'm flagging to close as a simple error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your **JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); });
```